# Write empty packets into avi file ffmpeg

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing

A task:
I have a trusted video event detector. I trust to my event detector for 100% and I want to write an uncompressed frame to my avi containter only if my event detector produces "true" result.
For frames, when my event detector is producing "false" I would like to write an empty packet because I want to know that there was a frame without event happening.
Is it possible to keep AVI file alive? Or do I need to write my own player in this case?

Another option is to calculate timestamps manually and set dts/pts to that calculated time.
Drawback: I will need to recalculate timestamps to understand how many frames were between events.

I am using:

> av_write_frame(AVFormatContext, AVPacket);

and

> av_interleaved_write_frame(AVFormatContext, AVPacket);

What is your suggestion/idea?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Knowing AVI spec, I don't think there is a such thing as an "empty packet" as AVI stores its frames densely without frame timestamps. If file-size is no issue, you can repeat the same frame to indicate undetected event (undo with freezedetect filter) or insert all-zero frame (undo with blackdetect filter). It, however, appears better to use something like matroska container and variable frame rate paired with a lossless h264 (more inline with your alternate option?). Just my 2 cents.

Comment: My idea was to use uncompressed images. Repeating same frame is not a great idea because file-size is an issue.